Max basement window span
I have an existing 32x14 window with no header. I plan on adding a 32x42 egress window. Do I need to add a header?

"longer" means taller?

Yes, please clarify all dimensions here.  You say it's not going to be wider, yet you're concerned about "span" (which is width).  Please provide a sketch showing existing and proposed conditions.

I clarified the question. Thanks in advanced.
